# Ionic custom header(ion-nav-bar) hides issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, header, navbar

I want to have in my app the same header(with Back button and other custom buttons) on each page.
I tried to define a custom ion-nav-bar in index.html as following:

```html
<html>
...
<body ng-app="starter">    
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
       <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons> 
  </ion-nav-bar>    
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body> </html>
```

and all the other pages looks like this:

```html
<ion-view view-title="PageN">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="article in articles" href="#/app/articles/{{article.id}}">
        {{article.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

After I launched the application, my custom navbar is hidden. I can see only default navbar.
How to customize the default navbar or how to replace it with a custom one?
I already tried some solutions including header but without success.
Anyone?

Comment: Make sure, that you have correct routing in your app.js. Please share your routes.

Comment: I work on default created app: ionic start conference sidemenu and the routing looks like:

.state('app.sessions', {
  url: "/sessions",
  views: {
      'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/sessions.html",
          controller: 'SessionsCtrl'
      }
  }
})

Comment: angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
url: '/app', abstract: true, templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html', controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/sessions');
});